# where I find the file modified by an android application

Tags: android, file

I want to save data in an output file using the following code. But I don't know where I find this file after the execution of the application.

```
      try {
// open myfilename.txt for writing
 OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput("myfile.txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE));
 // write the contents on mySettings to the file
 out.write("x="+Float.toString(xx)+"    y="+Float.toString(yy)+"    z="+Float.toString((zz))+"      Puissance="+Float.toString(magneticStrenght));
 // close the file
out.close();
} catch (java.io.IOException e) {
 //do something if an IOException occurs.
 Log.e("Exception", "File write failed: " + e.toString());
}
```

Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This file is stored into your Application Data. You can not view this file from File manager until your Phone is rooted.
So it will be better if you provide external directory path like:

```
File openfilename=  new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"myfile.txt");
 try {
// open myfilename.txt for writing
 FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(file);
 // write the contents on mySettings to the file
 PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(f);
     pw.println(("x="+Float.toString(xx)
+"    y="+Float.toString(yy)
+"       z="+Float.toString((zz))+"      Puissance="
+Float.toString(magneticStrenght));

 // close the file
 pw.flush();
    pw.close();
    f.close();
} catch (java.io.IOException e) {
 //do something if an IOException occurs.
 Log.e("Exception", "File write failed: " + e.toString());
}
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer. So I cannot simply save the file in internal storage memory?

Comment: Yes you can save it. But tell me exactly where you want to save the file. I have give you this answer to save file in internal storage of phone memory. Not in Application storage.

Answer (score 1):

This file is stored into your internal storage. You will not be able to view this file externally.
Give a path to external sd card for file storage if you want to view it externally